# Autolayout minimum gap between UIStackViews

Tags: ios, autolayout, ios-autolayout, uistackview

I have 3 UIStackViews laid as follows edge to edge:

```
   SV1 ---- SV2 ---- SV3
```

SV1 sits at a fixed distance of 5 points to superview leading, SV2 center is aligned with center of superview, and SV3 is at a fixed distance of 5 points to views trailing. Problem is on iPhone SE, SV2 is too wide and too close to SV1 and SV3. How do I set autolayout constraints so that SV2 is at a minimum distance D to SV1 and SV3?

Answer (score 0):

You can create two constraints: first between sv2 and sv1 and second between sv2 and sv3. The trick is to set the constraint **not** equals to a a value but **greater than**.

Answer (score 0):

You can create horizontal spacing constraints between the stack views and set them to greater-or-equal. This takes care of the minimum space between them.

But since they were to close together this means at least one of them has to get smaller to make space for the separation. You control which one by setting the *content compression resistance* priority of the views inside your stack views. The one with the lowest value shrinks.

If all three stack views have different widths you also could lower the priority of the center constraint to a value below the spacing constraints priority. That would mean that the center view is pushed to one side to make room for the spacing.

There are lots of possibilities that depend on your exact views. The best way is to experiment a bit with the priorities.